# How to stop submissive urination?

Tags: dogs, toilet-training, training

My 6-month old puppy pees when we scold him... I read that you're not supposed to yell at the dog when they mess up, but just now he ran out of the door even though he knows he's not supposed to and when I yelled at him to get back he peed all over the place. The other day he knocked some stuff over and I just grabbed him by the collar to lead him to his time-out spot and he peed again. I didn't spank him or yell or anything because I read that you're not supposed to do that, but I feel like not scolding him for submissive peeing is gonna give him the idea that it's working and that he should pee every time to avoid being scolded .... I don't know what to do. It's starting to get really annoying. I don't know if he's going to grow out of it.

Comment: A few questions: How is your dog behaviors in "normal" situations: Do you consider the dog to be shy, easily scared, nervous, easily excitable, etc.? Does your dog react in a submissive way when you call it by its name or seems anxious? Also, what kind of breed (size) is the dog?

Comment: @go-junta, he is just fine in normal situations. He doesn't pee when we call his name or come home from being away or from excitement in general (except one time when my boyfriend was rough housing with him and running around, the dog stopped and made a big puddle, from excitement I'm assuming).

Comment: @go-junta,  I think he is a little anxious because even though he sleeps through the night, he starts wining in the morning to be let out (first to pee outside, then just because he doesn't want to be in his crate anymore, if we put him right back). He's extremely excitable, but I think it's just cuz he's a puppy still. He's a tamaskan (german shepherd - husky - malamute mix).